# Confirming the existence of nested object properties

Tags: reactjs, syntax

I find myself needing to check for nested properties often, and I'm fairly comfortable with how I'm doing it. For example, let's say I want to do show a component if a specific property exists on a form:

```
// check if the form exists
const hasForm = !!myForms[formId]

// check if the property exists on the form
const hasProp = hasForm && !!myForms[formId]['propertyName']

// do something
hasProp && <SomeComponent />

// of course, I could check it in one check, but I may need 'hasForm'
const hasProp = !!myForms[formId] && !!myForms[formId]['propertyName']
```

My questions: 1) Is there a more succinct way to approach this? 2) Is this a safe approach, or is there a case in which this method could fail?

Comment: I've found an article that may help, especially with deeper nesting. https://medium.com/javascript-inside/safely-accessing-deeply-nested-values-in-javascript-99bf72a0855a

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use check condition in a single line.

This would be your case:

```
 (!!myForms[formId] && !!myForms[formId]['propertyName']) &&  <SomeComponent />
```

It won't check next all conditions if current condition return false. If we write condition in variable It will compare then later. Both have minor performance difference. But It is more about code readability which is our primal concern.

Answer (score -1):

You can use lodash `get` or [has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has).

```
const hasProp = has(myForms, `${formId}.${propertyName}`)
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. Please post as a comment instead.

Comment: @zzzzBov How is it not answering the question?

Comment: "You can use lodash get or has." was not a complete answer to the question when it was asked.